# Xcloud on Android, games say controller not connected, but it is

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, xbox-game-pass

Just been trying to use xcloud on my Huawei p10 pro, I blue toothed my xbox one controller to android and it seems to work as it can use the d pad to cycle though icons on the phone, but when I start up a game on xcloud the game says please reconnect the controller. Any idea whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to the wifi 2.4GHz but when I connect to 5GHz it worked fine.  Not sure if a bug with the app or what.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a cable and plug the controller into the phone. It has worked for me.